# Wait for something forever CasperJS/PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs, scraper

is there a way or work around to wait for something forever?

E.g.

I'll use fb as example because is the same thing on my site.
Every time that there are new post on my facebook timeline, shows up a panel 'Click here to load the posts'.

Basically, what I need is trigger some action after the panel is visible(click on it).
I know about waitUntilVisible, but it runs only one time and I'd like to run forever and capture many times.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can start the wait function anew when the timeout is reached. This works because the `onTimeout` callback to [`casper.waitUntilVisible`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waituntilvisible) will be executed inside the step function of `waitUntilVisible`.

```
function continuous(){
    casper.waitUntilVisible("#someSelector", function then(){
        // do something on success
    }, continuous);
}

casper.start(url).then(continuous).then(function(){/* something further */}).run()
```

If you never want to terminate, just use an impossible selector for `"#someSelector"` or a custom `waitFor`:

```
casper.waitFor(function check(){ return false; }, function then(){
    // do something on success
}, continuous);
```